# Blazor Server Side Token

Tags: html, httprequest, blazor

I have a question regarding to use of Token in Server Side Blazor Application.

I have a page on my Blazor Application, let´s call it "TestSite"

On this page i have a lot information. I want to extract the html from that site and print that in to a pdf.

What is the simplest way to do this?

My knoladge regarding HttpRequest is not strong. So please explain as simply as you can.

Comment: **extract the html**, do you want to print the code or print the rendered view?

Comment: @Karney. I want to print the code.

Comment: In the browser, right click-> view the source code -> right click -> print.